# Slack Interact Only Once with Messages

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm using interactive messages in Slack to ask the user for permission for an action, but I can't figure out how to do two things:

1. The user should only be able to interact with each message once, but interactive messages seem to be able to call the URL as many times as the user clicks on them.
2. Show which button was pressed (OK highlighted in green or NO in red, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would suggest responding directly with a new message to the button pressed request, which will overwrite the original message containing the buttons and prevent the user from pressing it again. See [here](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages#responding) for details on how it works.
2. You can not "highlight" a pressed button with Slack. Instead your response message could indicate textually what button was pressed / which action was chosen etc..